# Cannot share with UICloudSharingController; vanishes with "uploading" message

Tags: cloudkit, ckshare

while presenting the UICloudSharingController on top of a view, it presents the screen and when I select the messages option to send a message to a person whom I want to share with, it gives a spinning wheel with "uploading" message and vanishes - attached[image: screenshot].

However when I go to cloudkit dashboard the root record has been shared. But I cannot share it with specific person. Is it because it has shared global? How can I fix it?

```
self.shareInfraRecord(zoneID: appDelegate.privateContactZoneID, completion: { (status) in
     if ( status == false) {
             return
      }
    })

func shareInfraRecord(zoneID: CKRecordZone.ID, completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void) {
    
    if let rootRecord = self.rootRecord {
        if self.rootRecord?.share == nil {
            let sharingController = UICloudSharingController { (controller, preparationHandler: @escaping (CKShare?, CKContainer?, Error?) -> Void) in
                
                let shareID = CKRecord.ID(recordName: UUID().uuidString, zoneID: zoneID)
                var share = CKShare(rootRecord: rootRecord, shareID: shareID)
               
                share[CKShare.SystemFieldKey.title] = Cloud.ShareInfrastructure.ContactShareTitleKey as CKRecordValue?
                share[CKShare.SystemFieldKey.shareType] = Cloud.ShareInfrastructure.ContactShareTypeKey as CKRecordValue?
               
                let modifyRecZoneOp = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave:[rootRecord, share], recordIDsToDelete: nil)
                modifyRecZoneOp.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { (records, recordID, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        if let ckerror = error as? CKError {
                            if let serverVersion = ckerror.serverRecord as? CKShare {
                                share = serverVersion
                            }
                            completion(false)
                        }
                    }
                    preparationHandler(share, self.defaultContainer, error)

                }
                self.privateDB?.add(modifyRecZoneOp)
            }
        
            sharingController.availablePermissions = [.allowReadOnly, .allowPrivate]
            sharingController.delegate = self
            sharingController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        
            self.present(sharingController, animated:true, completion:nil)

    } else {
            let shareRecordID = rootRecord.share!.recordID
            let fetchRecordsOp = CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs: [shareRecordID])
        
            fetchRecordsOp.fetchRecordsCompletionBlock = { recordsByRecordID, error in
                guard error == nil, let share = recordsByRecordID?[shareRecordID] as? CKShare  else {
                    if let ckerror = error as? CKError {
                        self.aErrorHandler.handleCkError(ckerror: ckerror)
                        //self.saveToCloudKitStatus(recordName: myRecordName, success: false)
                    }
                    completion(false)
                    return
                }
               
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let sharingController = UICloudSharingController(share: share, container: self.defaultContainer!)
                    completion(true)
                    //completionHandler(sharingController)
                }
            }
            self.privateDB?.add(fetchRecordsOp)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When the UICloudSharingController crashes it gives error: 2020-08-31 22:33:46.303978-0500 rpxg[3789:1613179] [CK] Got a connection error for operation 49B9977581013179: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.cloudd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.cloudd}

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late but I was running into this issue too, while using `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` and it seems the issue was just making sure that my iCloud container name in the Capabilities section of the settings matched my app bundle name ie `iCloud.com.goddamnyouryan.MyApp`